# LightIRC is blank

Tags: irc

I am trying to join an IRC powered by LightIRC. Specifically I would like to join [this one.](http://eqmegathreads.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_31.html) It is simply some HTML embedded in blogger. I have already contacted the the person who installed this specific channel, however, my problem exists in all LightIRC embeds. Simply, it looks like this:
[image]

That's not supposed to happen. There is supposed to be text from the server above and a list of current users to the right. I can select a username and type messages, but I cannot submit them, and the Server button and the menu button to the left of the message both do jack squat. It works for others, but not for me. I believe the others are all on Windows. On Ubuntu this occurs in both Firefox and Chrome, with and without extensions disabled. When I switch to Windows, it works in both browsers regardless of extension status. Is there any way to fix this? I spend 99% of my time on Ubuntu so participating in this IRC would be VERY Impractical for me if I cannot fix it. I will also ask the installer for permission to post the channel here if anyone else would like to try it.

Comment: It could be a problem with your flash plugin. If you don't mind, can you post your Ubuntu, Firefox, and Flash versions?

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Also everything else in Flash works fine. I'm listening to a song on Youtube as we speak.

Comment: @EggheadDash YouTube doesn't use flash anymore. They use the html5 viedeo player